# Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I keep getting this error `Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined` and I can't understand why. I'm following a tutorial and it works for them but not for me even though our codes are the same. Here is the code.

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;
var db = new mongo.Db("nodejs-introduction", new mongo.Server(host, port, {}));
db.open(function(error) {

  console.log("We are connected " + host + ":" + port);

  db.collection("user", function(error, collection) {
    console.log("We have the collection");

    collection.insert({
        id: "1",
        name: "John Smith",
        twitter: "johns",
    }, function() {
      console.log("Successfully inserted John");
    });

    collection.insert({
        id: "2",
        name: "Eric Cartman",
        twitter: "cartman",
    }, function() {
      console.log("Successfully inserted Eric");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You have two inserts and a bunch of logs. How about telling where exectly something is not working and what can you see before this error.

Comment: I can see the two log statements. Then I see the error.

Comment: try printing the error.Chances are that you must have not connected to the db at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have never defined your variable `collection` and therefore it is undefined. Try `console.log(collection);` to check that this is true. I am surprised that this tutorial worked for someone.

To get rid of the problem, just define your collection with: `var collection = db.collection('user');`

Comment: @BidhanA use more engineering words. Doesn't work do not allow to understand your problem.

Comment: @BidhanA I mean the basic things: stuff like doesn't work, an error, crashed will not allow you to transition from a beginner to average. Try to explain as detailed as possible what exactly does not work, what kind of an error and so on.

Comment: @sajeshNambiar I have the same issue but I cannot solve it can you help?

Comment: In my case mongodb was not running, it should be running when you do some operation using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

try using this and see if it works:

```
var collection = db.get('user');

collection.insert({
    id: "1",
    name: "John Smith",
    twitter: "johns",
}, function() {
    console.log("Successfully inserted John");
});
```